# Does "What's New" field in Google Play Store in Staged Rollout is specific for this apk?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to use the staged rollout in the google play store for my app,

From What I understand all the media files can not be specific of each apk.

however when I publish a new apk there is the "What's New" field.

If I publish in staged rollout will the users that get the new build will be the only one to see that field, or like the media files it will be for everyone?

Does anyone tried it already and can check it out?....

Tnx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone interested, the "What's New" field is separated for each apk, so it is safe to put there the text for the staged out build (however screenshots are not ...)

You can even edit the what's new after you post the apk....